# Error designing new arrow in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm a trying to design a new arrow following instructions from the pgfmanual. I tried the example code (pp 610):

```
\pgfarrowsdeclare{arcs}{arcs}{...}
{
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt} % do not dash
\pgfsetroundjoin   % fix join
\pgfsetroundcap    % fix cap
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-10pt}{10pt}}
\pgfpatharc{180}{270}{10pt}
\pgfpatharc{90}{180}{10pt}
\pgfusepathqstroke
}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[-arcs,line width=3pt] (-2,0) -- (0,0);
\draw[arcs-arcs,line width=1pt] (-2,-1.5) -- (0,-1);
\useasboundingbox (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

But I get the following result instead of the one shown in the manual. Any suggestions?

[image: resultado]

Comment: Have you tried to read below the example, especially the part about the `...`. It goes like *Indeed, when the `...` is set appropriately (in a moment),*... You didn't set anything about ... right? It's on p.612

Comment: The code inside {...} is for the arrow extend, nothing to do with this...

Comment: Try including the rest and see if it works

Answer (score 1):

It is well running with `PGF 3.0`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\pgfarrowsdeclare{arcs}{arcs}{...}
{
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt} % do not dash
\pgfsetroundjoin   % fix join
\pgfsetroundcap    % fix cap
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-10pt}{10pt}}
\pgfpatharc{180}{270}{10pt}
\pgfpatharc{90}{180}{10pt}
\pgfusepathqstroke
}
\begin{document}
\section{Declaring an Arrow Tip Kind}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[-arcs,line width=3pt] (-2,0) -- (0,0);
\draw[arcs-arcs,line width=1pt] (-2,-1.5) -- (0,-1);
\useasboundingbox (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It seems to me that everyone should cut down on using v.3.0 as a solution until it at the very least makes it into CTAN, as it's clearly not helpful for the rest of us out there who are not "on the bleeding edge".

Comment: @ajeh I agree. Sorry that I also use v3. But can't resist it :)